# Как определить в переменную id пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть БД, где есть пользователи. Внедряю туда фотографии пользователей, но никак не могу решить вопрос с id. А именно: как определить какой пользователь загружает фото?

Вот сам БД: [image: База данных]

Определяется путь с помощью этого кода:

```
require_once 'mysql_connect.php';

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "user_photo/" . $name);

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_image = 'users_photo/$name' WHERE id = $id";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$name]);
```

Боль:

Мне надо определить в переменную id пользователя, чтобы при загрузке фотографии в БД отправлялось путь к фотографии, именно того пользователя, который загрузил фото.
Можете увидеть в коде, где подключаюсь к БД. Там есть неопределенная переменная $id

Comment: [CURRENT_USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user)

Comment: Что бы определить какой пользователь загружает фотографию, сначала нужно его идентифицировать, обычно это делается через стандартную авторизацию.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про куки и сессии, авторизовать пользователя и тогда, после авторизации, браузер так сказать будет хранить id пользователя по которому вы и сможете выдать ему на страницах то, что нужно, также и сможете идентифицировать данные полученные от конкретно этого пользователя!

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с Куки:

```
require_once 'mysql_connect.php';

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "user_photo/" . $name);
$login = $_COOKIE['login'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_image = 'users_photo/$name' WHERE login = '$login'";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$name]);
```

Comment: И теперь любой пользователь сможет загружать фотки для кого угодно. Нужно делать нормальную авторизацию а не просто сохранять логин в куки.

Comment: И кстати код запроса нерабочий. Тебе много раз говорили что нельзя писать переменные прямо в запрос